# Use IndexIgnore for all SubFolders

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf

I have an index, "books" which lists some html books on my domain.
A lot of the time, the html books have related sub-folders.
What I would like to do, is set things up so that people can only see the main link (.html in most cases)
I can't seem, to find the solution (I might just be googling the wrong question) on how to block a subdirectory from showing up in an index.

I imagine it's something along the lines of IndexIgnore books/*/

Currently I have this (in httpd.conf);

```
Directory "/var/www/domain/books"  
    Options Indexes
    IndexIgnore *.jpg
/Directory
```

Obviously, I need to add something in to get sub-directories of books to stop showing up, but I'm not really sure what/how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Options All -Indexes
```